# Working demo of state management in Polymer 2.x using Mixins

Tags: polymer, state, polymer-2.x, polymer-2.0

[Here, I'm trying to build a working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/SPjgt678pI1zzMIs68h2?p=preview) to implement the code contained in [this blog article](https://www.captaincodeman.com/2017/07/06/managing-state-in-polymer-20-beyond-parent-child-binding) written by @CaptainCodeman — *Managing State in Polymer 2.0 - Beyond Parent / Child Binding
Share state between separated DOM elements without Redux*.

I'm getting the following errors.

> run.plnkr.co/:5 GET https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.0.0/lib/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js
>
> run.plnkr.co/:1 GET https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/my-options.html 500 ()
>
> run.plnkr.co/:1 GET https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/shared-styles.html 500 ()
>
> my-view2.html:26
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError:
>
> MyOptionsMixin is not defined at my-view2.html:26

Does anyone have a working demo of this?

my-options.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">

<dom-module id="my-options">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        padding: 16px;
      }
      h3, p {
        margin: 8px 0;
      }
    </style>
    <h3>Options</h3>
    <p>
      <paper-checkbox checked="{{ options.subscribe }}">Send Notifications</paper-checkbox>
    </p>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {

      let optionsInstance = null;

      class MyOptions extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() { return 'my-options'; }

        static get properties() {
          return {
            options: {
              type: Object,
              value: () => ({
                subscribe: false
              })
            },
            subscribers: {
              type: Array,
              value: () => []
            }
          }
        }

        static get observers() {
          return [
            'optionsChanged(options.*)'
          ]
        }

        constructor() {
          super();

          if (!optionsInstance) optionsInstance = this;
        }

        register(subscriber) {
          this.subscribers.push(subscriber);
          subscriber.options = this.options;
          subscriber.notifyPath('options');
        }

        unregister(subscriber) {
          var i = this.subscribers.indexOf(subscriber);
          if (i > -1) this.subscribers.splice(i, 1)
        }

        optionsChanged(change) {
          for(var i = 0; i < this.subscribers.length; i++) {
            this.subscribers[i].notifyPath(change.path);
          }
        }
      }

      window.customElements.define(MyOptions.is, MyOptions);

      MyOptionsMixin = (superClass) => {
        return class extends superClass {
          static get properties() {
            return {
              options: {
                type: Object
              }
            }
          }

          connectedCallback() {
            super.connectedCallback();
            optionsInstance.register(this);
          }

          disconnectedCallback() {
            super.disconnectedCallback();
            optionsInstance.unregister(this);
          }
        }
      }
    }());
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

my-view2.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

<link rel="import" href="my-options.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="my-view2">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">2</div>
      <h1>View Two</h1>
      <p>Ea duis bonorum nec, falli paulo aliquid ei eum.</p>
      <p>Id nam odio natum malorum, tibique copiosae expetenda mel ea.Detracto suavitate repudiandae no eum. Id adhuc minim soluta nam.Id nam odio natum malorum, tibique copiosae expetenda mel ea.</p>

      <p>Send notifications option is: <b>[[ options.subscribe ]]</b></p>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    class MyView2 extends MyOptionsMixin(Polymer.Element) {
      static get is() { return 'my-view2'; }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MyView2.is, MyView2);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Edit: [Working Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/hMnFLA99RYWEGBwzbPQf?p=preview) (accepted answer forked and edited)

Comment: AFAIK, at present, [this blog article](https://www.captaincodeman.com/2017/07/06/managing-state-in-polymer-20-beyond-parent-child-binding) and [this working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/P55mSoApzVz7UhHRu6j6?p=preview) represent the best practice for state management in Polymer. It seems more popular than [tur-nr/polymer-redux](https://github.com/tur-nr/polymer-redux). Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/P55mSoApzVz7UhHRu6j6?p=preview)

---

> run.plnkr.co/:5 GET https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.0.0/lib/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js

Your `<script>` tag imports a non-existent file:

```
https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.0.0/lib/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js
```

I would use the same `polygit.org` URL that was used in the rest of the Plunker:

```
https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/
```

Also, the script name no longer includes `min`. The actual filename is `webcomponents-lite.js`. The `<script>` tag should look like this:

```
<script src="https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
```

---

> run.plnkr.co/:1 GET https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/my-options.html 500 ()
>
> run.plnkr.co/:1 GET https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/shared-styles.html 500 ()

`my-view2.html` sets `<base href>` to `polygit.org`, and then tries to import `my-options.html` and `shared-styles.html`, both of which only exist in the Plunker sandbox:

```
<!-- my-view2.html -->
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/">
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer-element.html">

<link rel="import" href="my-options.html"> <!-- https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/my-options.html -->
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html"> <!-- https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/shared-styles.html -->
```

The only file imported here that needs to come from `polygit.org` is `polymer-element.html`, so you could remove the `<base>` tag and move the URL prefix to that import:

```
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
```

---

> my-view2.html:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: 
>   MyOptionsMixin is not defined at my-view2.html:26

`my-view2` does not declare/instantiate `my-options`, so the `script` that defines `MyOptionsMixin` is never executed. You could resolve this simply by declaring it in `my-view2`'s template:

```
 <dom-module id="my-view2">
    <template>
      <my-options></my-options>
    </template>
    ...
 </dom-module>
```